# Wordpress not handling subdirectory properly

Tags: directory, installation

I have placed a new wordpress install in http://www.forerunnerintl.org/blog and it seems to be running and have my old posts that I updated.

All the links, though, go to http://forerunnerintl.org instead of http://forerunnerintl.org/blog and so they are all dead. How do I configure wordpress to handle the subdirectory properly?

I'm having problems logging in as well since those links are also dead.

Comment: Start here: [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_Directories_On_Your_Existing_Server)

Comment: Nope. Updating the path specified here gives me /blog/blog. Must be another setting, @GregMcMullen

Comment: The links won't auto update. However you could run a sql query to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://deliciousbrains.com/how-why-install-wordpress-core-subdirectory/ and updated two fields in the wp_options table: siteurl and home. After updating both of these, my site appears to be working correctly.